# How to get all departments in an organization using MS Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below code to find department name:

```
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = connectToGraphAPI(Globals.adTenantId, Globals.adClientId, Globals.adClientSecret);

var Peoples = await graphServiceClient.Users[userid].People.Request().GetAsync();
foreach (Person People in Peoples) {
    if (People.DisplayName != null && People.DisplayName.Equals(userName)) {
        return People.Department.ToString();
    }
}
```

But, I want to get list of all departments in an organization rather than finding Departments of specific user.

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36169182/9534819)

Comment: Hi @Matt.G But this Code is looping through users, i already have a code which loops through users and fetch departmentName. But,i want to fetch departmentName without using user loop.

Comment: Department is a string value under the Job Info section on the User-Profile page. in other words, it is just a string property on User Profile, just like Job Title is..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like @Matt.G said, Department is a string value under the Job Info section on the User-Profile page. There is no api to list all departments in an organization. You need to loop through users to fetch departmentName.

Comment: Why doesn’t MSFT create a separate endpoint to get all departments in 1 API call just like the Google Directory API instead of potentially making hundreds of API calls to do the exact same thing for large companies?